# How can I set up a github fine-grained token to push a tag?

Tags: authentication, github, security, tags

I'm trying to push a new tag to my existing github.com public project. In the past I've used "legacy" tokens because setting up the fine-grained token never worked. Now I'm trying to figure out why it hasn't worked.

I created a token, specifying "All repositories" under Repository access. Under Repository permissions, I selected Contents (R/W), metadata (R/O), and Pull requests (R/W). I selected nothing under Account permissions.

When I try the `git push origin <mytag>`, it asks me for my user name and password and I use the new token for the password. I just get `remote: Permission to <repo> denied to <username>`.

The URL for the repo is just `https://github.com/<repo>.git`. What am I missing?